# php webpayments pro install.php not working

Tags: curl, paypal, php

I am trying to run php install.php for paypal webpayments pro. However when I try to do this from the command line on windows server 2003, by doing php -the directory- install.php it returns the error:

```
INSTALLATION ERROR: one or more extensions are missing: cURL
```

I have triple checked my php.ini and phpinfo() and both show that cURL is enabled and installed. The directory I am trying to install it on is in the D drive while the php.ini file is in the C drive, not sure if that could have something to do with it, but then phpinfo would tell me if I was enabling curl on the wrong ini file so I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There usually are two different `php.ini` files : one for IIS and one for PHP-CLI (command line).

In command line, try `php -i` to see what `php.ini` file is really used.

Comment: Thank you went in to php/php.ini changed it to be enabled fixed the problem